# Connecting R with Vertica Database

Tags: r, vertica

I have installed the Vertica R language version (.rpm) file. But still I am unable to create libraries. 
Please let me know how to install JDBC (.jar) file and also install.package (RJDBC). 
It is showing this error...

Warning in install.packages("RJDBC", dep = TRUE) :
'lib = "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library"' is not writable
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://ftp.iitm.ac.in/cran/bin/windows/contrib/3.0
Warning message:
package ‘RJDBC’ is not available (for R version 3.0.2)

Please help me with the procedure how to setup R with verica.

Thanks
Sameer

Comment: which version of Vertica are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to get connected via JDBC, see this answer: [Connect R and Vertica using RODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17285503/connect-r-and-vertica-using-rodbc/17306014#17306014)