# JDBC Vertica Connection using R Studio

Tags: r, jdbc, vertica

I am facing following error during connecting JDBC server using R Studio.

> dbGetQuery(vertica, q)
>   Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
>     unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbGetQuery’ for signature ‘"JDBCConnection", "function"’
>
> query = dbSendQuery(vertica, "SET ROLE bi_analysts")
>   Error in .verify.JDBC.result(r, "Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for ",  : 
>     Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for SET ROLE bi_analysts (No results were returned by the query.)

Comment: Looks like a problem with `namespace`.  Can you post value of `vertica`? Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17285503/connect-r-and-vertica-using-rodbc) also.

Comment: Thanks sKwa, Problem with vpn. Now its working.