# Connect R to Vertica DB for data transformation and modelling?

Tags: r, vertica, dbvisualizer, rjdbc

I have recently started working on Vertica Database using DBVisualizer. Given that I have experience in R and am quite comfortable, can anyone help me understanding what all I'll need to connect to Vertica from R (RStudio) and execute the queries.

Any documentation on how to start will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I've had success following the official documentation for [ODBC DSN](https://my.vertica.com/docs/9.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/ConnectingToVertica/InstallingDrivers/CreatingAnODBCDataSourceNameDSN.htm) and using the [RODBC](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RODBC) package. There are always warnings in R when I disconnect, but I think they can be ignored.

Comment: See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17285503/connect-r-and-vertica-using-rodbc/)

Answer (score 1):

We use [RJDBC](http://rforge.net/RJDBC/) for that task. Example:

```
library(RJDBC)
...
# load dataframe from an sql query
loadDataFromQuery <- function(query) {
  #library(RJDBC)
  strt <- Sys.time()
  vDriver <- JDBC(driverClass="com.vertica.jdbc.Driver", classPath="/opt/vertica/java/lib/vertica-jdk5.jar")
  vertica <- dbConnect(vDriver, "jdbc:vertica://myverticaserver.com:5433/somedb", "myuser", "mypass")
  df <- dbGetQuery(vertica, query)
  dbDisconnect(vertica)
  print(Sys.time()-strt)
  return(df)
```